# StopIteration error after breaking out of a Generator

Tags: python-2.7, generator

I am trying to read a binary file a chunk at a time. Each time the generator would yeild 1024 bytes of data. When I want to stop i call the generator with .send('Stop'). I get the output correctly but I get an exception. Am I doing something wrong or is this expected in which case how do I handle this?

```
def read_epoch_from_file(filename,size=1024):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            read_data = f.read(size)
            if read_data:
                y = yield read_data
                if y == 'Stop':
                    print 'Stopped'
                    break
            else:
                break
        print 'End'
        f.close()
        return

gen = read_epoch_from_file("Test")
readdata_ascii = next(gen)
#do somthing
readdata_ascii = next(gen)
#do somthing
readdata_ascii = next(gen)
#do somthing
gen.send('Stop')
```

Output seen

```
Stopped
End

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\CVS sandbox\Mandela2\Extractor\binary_parser.py", line 50, in <module>
    gen.send('Stop')
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the `StopIteration` is always produced by the generator when there is no more `yield` values left. This exception is usually consumed automatically within a `for` loop. In my case the exception would bubble up, until I have a `try/except` statement block to deal with it. Below is the code I have used to handle this exception. If this is not the best way to do this please let me know.

```
try:
    gen = read_epoch_from_file("Test")
    readdata_ascii = next(gen)
    #do somthing
    readdata_ascii = next(gen)
    #do somthing
    readdata_ascii = next(gen)
    #do somthing
    gen.send('Stop')
except StopIteration:
    pass
finally:
    del gen
```